# Android WebView: offline manifest vs local files

Tags: android, webview

I'm developing a simple Android App where the user must fill in a very complex form, for which I believe it's much easier to use an HTML form than an Android Activity with tons of `TextViews`.

The data collected by the form must be sent to some remote database, and the application must be able to work offline.

I thought of two alternatives, the question is: which one would be better?

1. Let a WebView load a remote website with an offline manifest
2. Let a WebView load a local website in assets folder

My second question is related to the storage when offline, and once again I have two options, and I don't know which one is better:

1. Using the HTML5 local storage, and let HTML + javascript send data to the server when online again
2. Let my Android app catch the form data, and handle everything the Android way.

Any input will be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the first question: depends on how often will you need to update your form. An online cached form can be updated quickly, while bundled pages are only updateable together with the app, and you will need to consider that both legacy and new clients can connect to your server at the same time (users will procrastinate updating).

Another aspect is portability. Do you envision an iOS version of your app, or perhaps a mobile site? If yes, then an HTML5 solution is definitely more portable. Also, debugging an app which is entirely HTML or entirely native is usually easier than a hybrid one -- you can stay within a single debugger.

Perhaps, one drawback of using HTML local storage inside WebView is that the data you save will be in a kind of a "black box" -- you will not be able to back it up easily.

[Added later] OK -- one drawback of putting your site into `assets` folder is that you'll have to use `file:` scheme in order to access it. This can lead to some cross-origin loading access related issues if you will try to mix your bundled content with content from the web. Check these WebView settings for example: `setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs`, `setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs`, `setMixedContentMode`.

Comment: I appreciate very much your input. I don't mind accepting your answer, but just to be sure... in your opinion, would any combination of alternatives (local vs remote + HTML5 sync vs Android sync) be wrong?

Comment: @Merlevede: I'm not quite sure what do you mean by "wrong", but... First of all, those two choices are completely orthogonal -- in your app you can have any combination of them, and any combination will work on not very ancient versions of Android (I guess, both AppCache and local storage are supported since Froyo). Perhaps, the only drawback of loading your site from `assets` folder, is that `file:` scheme URLs can add headache from security point of view in newer versions of WebView. Please see my addition to the answer.